# Inverted Commas are not replaced by spaces and not showing in listview

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver, sms

I develop an SMS Application in which when a SMS is received it is saved in the listview of my application. Now the problem is that if the message contains inverted commas then it is not saving in the database and thus not showing in listview. However i tried different methods available on net but none of them work. I then use Log.e to determine whether the incoming message is replacing the inverted comma or not but it doesnot replacing the inverted comma. My code for receiving sms is:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
  String msg_from="";
  String msgBody = "";
  String msgDate="";
  String title="";

  if (bundle != null) {
    try {

      Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
      msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

         msgBody += msgs[i].getDisplayMessageBody();

             msgBody.replace("\"","");
         Log.e("answer", msgBody);
```

I check in the last line but if I write "Hello and send it to my self then following error shown in logcat:

```
near "HELLO": syntax error (code 1): 
while compiling: insert into smss(contactnumber,contactname,message,date)
values ("03329234863", "03329234863",""HELLO ","1464940881000")
```

I also tried to replace msgBody with these solutions but none of them work:

```
 msgBody.replaceAll("\"","");
 msgBody.replace("\"","\\\\\"");
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Removing double quotes from a String works like this in Java:

```
String replaced = original.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

So your first attempt will work as expected. If it did not work for you, you likely have an issue somewhere else, ie are not passing the replaced string to the database. You did not post that code, but I guess there's an issue somewhere.

Comment: I first thought it too that maybe there is an issue of putting string in database but then i check by trying Log.e so that whenever sms receives i can see that what is logcat doing and when i saw that then the following error shown that i showed above. so basically it means that string is not converting at first :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
String first = second.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of the solution.